# Trace backlog user stories to requirements in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, requirements, user-stories

I work on the IT site in an agile project where the business uses a back log and user stories to capture business requirements. The IT team uses Enterprise architect to model the application, system requirements being one of the elements.

What are the best practices for tracing the backlog user stories to the system requirements? Reason for tracing is to demonstrate the business requirements have been implemented.

And how to handle user stories that changes a EA requirement? Trace the req to both user stories? As one user story will be invalid this somehow feels redundant?

A briljant idea, anyone? Silver bullet also accepted..

Comment: I think your question is simply too broad. The whole requirements capturing process fills book. And that will not include change management which takes a couple of other books. Basically use trace/realize with requirements.

Comment: For we decided on duplicating the user stories in EA and use the trace/realize association. When one user story invalidates a former we use color coding and a text explanation to point this out. Thanks

Comment: That's a good way. We also used MDG with shape script that colors depending on Status.

Answer (score 0):

Import user stories back into EA using the [connector](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/atlassian.confluence.plugins.eaconnector/cloud/overview). Then, use the [built-in Traceability tools of EA](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/traceability.html) to create the mappings to your other EA artifacts.

From my experience, it is better to involve future users actively and trains them to use new features by themselves. They'll keep that in mind better than a backwards traceability result chart in EA. And there is no better proof for an achieved implementation than the implementation itself, along with a successfully passed test case.